# Update order status after order confirmation

Tags: php, module, prestashop-1.6

I face a problem with my Prestashop module. I'm developing a module for payment. It works but I have a problem with the order status. I close the order before the payment (because I have to send the reference to bank which is generated after the order confirmation). Then when the payment is accepted my bank returns to me a php file that I want to edit in order to change the order status from "Awaiting payment" to "Payment accepted", how can I achieve that?

I'm using Prestashop 1.6.1.4

Thank you for every suggestion or information you can provide.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `PaymentModule.php` class you can find how the order status is set after the order is created

```
$new_history = new OrderHistory();
$new_history->id_order = (int) $order->id;
$new_history->changeIdOrderState((int) $id_order_state, $order, true);
```

Do you absolutely need to send the order reference to the bank though? My shops just send the order id which you can get with `Order::getNextOrderId()` before you actually create it.

Comment: I have to send to bank the order id, and my bank return an error if I send 2 times the same order id, so I have to close the order to get the id, and in case I have to change something in my order I can send another order id and the bank doesn't return error and I can proceed with payment (it sounds stupid but is the only way I found it work). So I want to update the order status after the payment is accepted. The only way I can think of is to update it in the php file that the bank return after successful payment.

Comment: Btw, if I use Order::getNextOrderId() isn't there the possibility that if 2 users do the checkout in same time but one finish before the other the order_id passed to the bank can differ from the one in the backoffice?

Comment: `Order::getNextOrderId()` sounds tricky to me if you consider that another transaction can take place at the same time..